# Elasticseach exists query on object type returns 0 results

Tags: rest, api, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

[UPD] Elasticsearch version is 5.6

I have the following mapping defined in `foo_index`:

```
{
    "foo": { 
        "properties": {
            "bar": { 
               "type": "object",
               "dynamic": false
            }
            ...
        } 
    } 
}
```

Some documents in `foo_index` contain `bar` property with arbitrary json data, while others do not. So the documents stored in `foo_index` look like the following:

```
[
    { bar: { arbitrary: { json: 1 } }, ... },
    { bar: { arbitrary: { json: 2 } }, ... },
    { ... }, // bar property is absent,
    { bar: { arbitrary: { json: 3 } }, ... }
]
```

When I execute the following query to fetch only those objects that contain `bar` property I get 0 results:

```
GET foo_index/foo/_search
{
    "query": {
        "exists": {
            "field": "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this query work? I'd expect it to return `foo` documents which contain `bar` property.

Comment: Could you please let me know which version of ES are you using? That'd be helpful.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal, sorry forgot to mention it. The version is 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are not able to view the documents is because you have set the field `dynamic: false` in your mapping.

So basically when you do that, you are telling elasticsearch *to not* create a separate inverted index for that field. Basically that field although exists in the document, it won't be a searchable field. As a result no query would be applicable on that field. In other words, ES would behave as if there's no such field.

As mentioned in [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html), we have the below when it is set to `false`

> Newly detected fields are ignored. These fields will not be indexed so
>   will not be searchable but will still appear in the _source field of
>   returned hits. These fields will not be added to the mapping, new
>   fields must be added explicitly.

Basically change your mapping to below:

### Mapping:

```
PUT foo_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "foo":{
      "properties": {
        "bar":{
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The [Exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) would work fine if you remove that field in your mapping.

Note that you would need to delete your index, re-create the index with the change in mapping, re-ingest the documents and then try the query.

Comment: Did the above resolve the issue you were facing? Is there anything else you would want?